# ListView updated only after all SMS loaded

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite, loader, android-cursoradapter

I have two Loaders. First one loads SMS to my DB. Second one loads SMS from my DB to cursor adapter. And I have my listView updated only after all SMSes inserted into my DB.

Here is loaders and adapter:

```
...
    private static final int SMS_LOADER = 0;
    private static final int MY_DB_LOADER = 1;
    MyCursorAdapter mAdapter;
...
```

Here is `initLoader`'s in `onCreate`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, null);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
...
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(SMS_LOADER, null, this);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(MY_DB_LOADER, null, this);
    }
```

Here is `onCreateLoader` with 2 loaders:

```
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        switch (id) {
            case SMS_LOADER: {
                String[] projection = {
                        BaseColumns._ID,
                        Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.DATE_SENT,
                        Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.BODY
                };

                return new CursorLoader(this,
                        BASE_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
            }
            case MY_DB_LOADER: {
                String[] projection = {
                        MyEntry._ID,
                        MyEntry.COLUMN_1,
                        MyEntry.COLUMN_2
                };

                return new CursorLoader(this,
                        MyEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                        projection,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
            }
            default:
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unsupported id " + id);
                return null;
        }
    }
```

In `onLoadFinished` I'm going through SMS cursor and inserting in my DB:

```
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        int id = loader.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case SMS_LOADER:
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    int columnIndexDateSent = data.getColumnIndex(Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.DATE_SENT);
                    int columnIndexBody = data.getColumnIndex(Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.BODY);

                    String date = data.getString(columnIndexDateSent);
                    String body = data.getString(columnIndexBody);

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                    values.put(MyEntry.COLUMN_1, date);
                    values.put(MyEntry.COLUMN_2, body);

                    getContentResolver().insert(MyEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
                }
                break;
            case MY_DB_LOADER:
                mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Unsupported id " + id);
        }
    }
```

I guess it is not a proper place to make inserts, cause Android Studio keep saying:

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Where should I move those inserts? How to make listView being updated after first row inserted into DB?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one. Created new class `FillDB extends AsyncTask`, moved code that fills DB into `doInBackground` and called `new FillDB().execute(data);` in `onLoadFinished`.